# Rails Order by Scope with Draper/Decorate from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a pretty complex model that is using a scope to establish what is considered online and what is considered offline. Then in my admin module I'm displaying all of the available devices. What I'm looking to do is then order by those that are currently online.

So the model looks like:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tokenizer

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :former_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'former_user_id'
  belongs_to :order

  belongs_to :replaced_by_device, class_name: 'Device', foreign_key: 'replaced_by_device_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user_clients, join_table: :user_clients_devices
  has_many :user_client_speed_tests, through: :user_clients
  validates :hardware_token, uniqueness: true, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :mac, mac_address: true, allow_blank: false, allow_nil: true

  before_validation :generate_hardware_token, on: :create
  before_validation :assign_organization_id_if_missing

  validate :existence_of_user_id, if: :user_id?
  validate :existence_of_organization_id, if: :organization_id?
  validates_numericality_of :user_id, :organization_id, allow_nil: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0

  alias_attribute :name, :mac

  scope :with_macs, -> { where("mac IS NOT NULL AND hardware_mac <> ''") }
  scope :without_macs, -> { where("mac IS NULL OR hardware_mac = ''") }
  scope :with_old_macs, -> { where("mac LIKE :prefix", prefix: "C0%") }
  scope :with_new_macs, -> { where("mac LIKE :prefix", prefix: "A%") }
  scope :without_user, -> { where(user_id: nil) }
  scope :with_user, -> { where.not(user_id: nil) }
  scope :online, -> { where("last_seen_at > ?", 1.hour.ago) }
  scope :offline, -> { where.not(id: online.ids) }
  scope :installed_online, -> { installed.online }
  scope :installed_offline, -> { installed.where.not(id: installed_online.ids) }

  enum status: [ :operational, :replaced ]

  after_save :set_provisioned_if_needed

  has_paper_trail

  ransacker :mac_address_presence, formatter: proc{ |value|
    value.eql?('present') ? with_macs.ids : without_macs.ids
  }, splat_params: true do |parent| parent.table[:id] end

  ransacker :mac_address_type, formatter: proc{ |value|
    value.eql?('old') ? with_old_macs.ids : with_new_macs.ids
  }, splat_params: true do |parent| parent.table[:id] end

  ransacker :organization_presence, formatter: proc{ |value|
    value.eql?('present') ? with_organization.ids : without_organization.ids
  }, splat_params: true do |parent| parent.table[:id] end

  ransacker :installation_status, formatter: proc{ |value|
    case value
    when 'installed' then installed.ids
    when 'not_installed' then not_installed.ids
    when 'not_assigned' then not_assigned.ids
    end
  }, splat_params: true do |parent| parent.table[:id] end

  ransacker :connection_status, formatter: proc{ |value|
    data = value.eql?('online') ? online.ids : offline.ids
    data.any? ? data : nil
  }, splat_params: true do |parent| parent.table[:id] end

  ransacker :wifi_signal_strength, formatter: proc{ |value|
    data =  case value
        when 'borderline' then with_borderline_signal_strength.ids
        when 'bad' then with_bad_signal_strength.ids
        when 'ok' then with_ok_signal_strength.ids
        when 'good' then with_good_signal_strength.ids
        else with_great_signal_strength.ids end
data.any? ? data : nil
  }, splat_params: true do |parent| parent.table[:id] end

  def update_status(new_status)
    update!(status: new_status, status_last_changed_at: Time.now.utc)
  end

  def can_replace_hw?
    operational? && (order.nil? || (order.present? && order.completed?))
  end

  def last_user_client
    user_clients.last
  end

  def last_user_client_speed_test
    last_user_client.last_speed_test if last_user_client.present?
  end

  def speed_tests
    user_client_speed_tests
  end
  def has_last_user_client?
    last_user_client.present?
  end

  def has_been_seen?
    has_last_user_client? && last_user_client.last_seen_at.present?
  end

  def offline?
    if has_been_seen?
      last_user_client.last_seen_at < 1.hour.ago
    end
  end

  def online?
    if has_been_seen?
      last_user_client.last_seen_at > 1.hour.ago
    end
  end

  def connection_status_history
    last_seen_history = last_seen_histories.where('last_seen_at > ?', 2.weeks.ago).order(:last_seen_at).to_a
    status_history = []
    while last_seen_history.present?
      next_last_seen = last_seen_history.shift
      status_history << {
          status: "Online",
          timestamp: next_last_seen.last_seen_at.in_time_zone(Time.now.zone)
      }

      if (last_seen_history.first&.last_seen_at || Time.current) - status_history.last[:timestamp] > 1.hour
        status_history << {
            status: "Offline",
            timestamp: status_history.last[:timestamp].in_time_zone(Time.now.zone) + 1.hour
        }
      end
    end

    status_history
  end

end
```

Then in my admin view I have an input I'm referencing with:

```
= f.input :user_device_ids, label: false, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: @organization.available_devices.decorate
```

So from the organization I'm wanting to order by the online Devices. I thought I could do something like @organization.available_devices.order(online).decorate. That clearly fails because online is a scope of Devices not from Organization. So if I do something like @organization.available_devices.order(Device.online).decorate I get no errors. That seems wrong/sloppy.

How do I accurately display for the collection the online devices in the different model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things came up looking at your code sample:

1. You have `belongs_to :order` which could easily be confused with ActiveRecord's `order` method: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order
2. If you temporarily remove that `belongs_to :order` and try `@organization.available_devices.order(:last_seen_at, :desc).decorate`
   things should work as expected.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: I absolutely hate that I didn't even think of that.